# Gorgon Recluse and Cunning Evasion

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If [Gorgon Recluse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGorgon%20Recluse%5d) is blocked and returned to my hand via [Cunning Evasion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCunning%20Evasion%5d), does it still destroy the blocking creature at end of combat?